# Unable to connect to the Oracle 19c from a client

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I'm using Oracle 19c. I have tested the connection by the commands "ping [ip]" and "tnsping", and both were successfully connected. Now, I want to connect to the Oracle developer from a client, and it is not be able to connect.
When I was using Oracle 12c, there was no such a problem. I really don't know what's going wrong here.

Comment: What does "I want to connect to the Oracle developer from a client" mean? To me, it doesn't make any sense. We are connecting to the **database** using some tool. Did you, by any chance, try to connect to the database using Oracle SQL Developer GUI tool? If so, how are you trying to establish connection? What did you enter into SQL Developer? How did it respond? Or are you using Allround Automations' PLSQL Developer GUI tool? If so, the same questions remain.

Comment: @Littlefoot I have tested the connection to PLSQL developer by the mentioned commands, from the client (weblogic) which has a specific IP address. the connections are run successfully. but, it is not available to connect to the PLSQL developer from the client (which has specific IP address).

Comment: show us what you're trying, show us what happens when you try (connection properties and error messages)

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I tested the connection by "ping ip" and "tnsping" from weblogic remote (with ip address ****) to database remote (with ip address ####). Now in the weblogic mode, I want to enter to the plsql developer. I entered the username, password, and database name, but it said invalid username/password logon denied.

Comment: Finally - 'invalid username/password'.  I was beginning to think you'd never give us an actual error.  Ok, so oracle is too dumb to lie about that error. It definitively means you reached _a_ datatabase (not necessarily the one you think) and the username and/or password you presented was incorrect for that database. Consider 1) you didn't reach the db you think, and 2) passwords are probably case-sensitive.

Comment: @nastaran *it is not available to connect to the PLSQL developer from the client* - that doesn't make sense. You can't connect *to* [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/), it's a desktop application. That would be like trying to connect to Notepad. You are trying to get your Weblogic application to connect to the **database**, surely?